# Make: No main target

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to make `make` not have a main target, meaning that invocations to `make` without a specified target would fail, even if a first target exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifically that, but if you are using GNU make there are ways to ensure users provide a goal on the command line.

First, you could check `MAKECMDGOALS`:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),)
$(error Missing command line goal!)
endif
```

Or alternatively you could use `.DEFAULT_GOAL` to force the default goal to be a rule that fails:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL = fail
fail:; @echo Missing command line goal; exit 1
```